# Limit of sequence and constant

Tags: limits

We know that $r_n \in [-10; 10]$ and $a_0 = 700$, $a_{n+1} = 4a_n + r_n$. I have to prove existence of such constant $C$ that $|a_n| \le C \cdot (4,1)^n$ and find limit of $\frac{a_n + (4,2)^n}{(4,2)^n - n^{40}4^n}$. I don't know even how to begin...

Comment: Begin by evaluating the first terms and look for a pattern. Try $r_n=0,10,-10$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Divide your recurrence relation by $4^{n+1}$. Then show that for $n\geq 1$, $\displaystyle \frac{a_n}{4^n}=a_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{r_k}{4^{k+1}}$, and that the series $\displaystyle \frac{r_k}{4^{k+1}}$ is (absolutely) convergent. Hence $a_n=4^n c_n$ with $c_n$ convergent to $\displaystyle L=700+\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{r_k}{4^{k+1}} >0$.